# Find Combinations of middle elements in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, traveling-salesman

I have a vector `vector<Points>list_of_points;` that contains the points A B C D A. I want to find all the possible combinations of the vector keeping the outer two elements in the same place. For example,
A B C D A -- A B D C A -- A C B D A -- A C D B A -- A D B C A -- A D C B A. Any advice on how I can do this?

I am doing this because each point has an x,y coordinate. I am trying to find the shortest distance to go to all the elements and return back to the original element. I am thinking to set the minimum distance equal to the first combination A B C D A, and compare all other combinations

```
//pseudocode
min distance = distance of A B C D A

while(there are still combinations){
   find another combinations of the vector.
   if that distance is smaller than min distance, make it the new min distance 
   save the path in a vector
}
```

If needed here is my implementation

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
  private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    string m_name;

  public:
    Point(int x, int y, string name)
      : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_name(name)
    {}
    
    Point(){};
    
    int getX() const {return m_x;}
    void setX(int x) {m_x=x;}

    int getY() const {return m_y;}
    void setY(int y) {m_y=y;}

    string getName() const {return m_name;}
    
    
    float getDistance(Point &other);

    string toString() const;

    void printPoint() const;

    // used for printing Point using << operator. For example:
    // Point p(1,2,"A");
    // cout << p << endl;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Point &p);

};

class ListOfPoints
{ 
  private:
    int elements;
    
  public:
    vector<Point>sorted_list;
    vector<Point>unsorted_list;
    
    void Unsorted_add(Point &newPt);
    void Sorted_add(Point &newPt);
    void Create_unsorted();
    void Sort_list();
    
    void set_elements(int n);
    int get_elements();
    
    
    ListOfPoints();

    // adds a new point to the end of the list
    void addPoint(Point &newPt);
    
    // prints the list of points
    void printList() const;
    
    // draws the points
    void draw() const;

};

string Point::toString() const{
  // examples how to create string from small parts
  string str(m_name);
  str += " = (";
  str += std::to_string(m_x);
  str.append(",").append(std::to_string(m_y)).append(")");
  return str;
} 

float Point::getDistance(Point &other){
  float x1 = float(this->getX());
        cout << "this->x = "<< this->getX() <<endl;
        cout << "this->y = "<<this->getY() <<endl;
        float y1 = float(this->getY());
        float x2 = float(other.getX());
        float y2 = float(other.getY());
        //cout << "x = " << x2 << endl;
        //cout << "y = " << y2 << endl;
        float dist = sqrt( pow(x2-x1,2) + pow(y2-y1,2) );
        cout << "dist = " << dist << endl;
        return dist;
}
void Point::printPoint() const{
  cout << toString() << endl;
}

// used for printing Point using << operator.
// For example, the following code will work
// Point origin(0,0,'O');
// cout << origin;
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Point &p) {
  return os << p.toString();
}

ListOfPoints::ListOfPoints() {

}


void ListOfPoints::Sorted_add(Point &newPt)  {
  sorted_list.push_back(newPt);
}

void ListOfPoints::Unsorted_add(Point &newPt)  {
  unsorted_list.push_back(newPt);
}


void ListOfPoints::set_elements(int n){
  elements = n;
}

int ListOfPoints::get_elements(){
  return this->elements;
}

void ListOfPoints::Create_unsorted(){
  int x;
  int y;
  string name;
  
  cout << "Enter the Number of elements" << endl;
  cin >> elements;
  for(int i = 0; i<elements; i++){
    cout << "Enter the name of the element: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout <<"Enter the x value" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout <<"Enter they y vlaue" << endl;
    cin >> y;
    Point p(x,y,name);
    unsorted_list.push_back(p);
    
  }

  cout << elements << endl;
  return;
}
```

Comment: there would be nPn number of results : where n is size of vector - 2, and nPn means permutation. You will probably have to find a way to limit it, otherwise there will be a whole lot of results

Comment: The standard library has a function for finding permutations called [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation). You can just give it iterators to the second and last element as the range to permute and then manually add the first and last value.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315836/algorithm-to-determine-the-fastest-route-passing-in-all-points look through this for a better algorithm, since brute forcing it might not be feasible for longer vectors, brute force has a complexity O(n!)

Answer (score 1):

Going by your description, the following program demonstrates what you are trying to achieve using [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "ABCDA";

    // sort the items after the beginning and before the end of the sequence
    std::sort(test.begin() + 1, std::prev(test.end()));
    do
    {
        std::cout << test << "\n";
      // permute the middle elements
    } while (std::next_permutation(test.begin() + 1, std::prev(test.end())));
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDA
ABDCA
ACBDA
ACDBA
ADBCA
ADCBA
```

---

To expand this to your `Point` class, you will need to sort the middle points in some way, and then apply the same logic using `std::next_permutation`.

Here is a small example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    int get_x() const { return m_x; }
    int get_y() const { return m_y; }
    Point(int x = 0, int y = 0) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
};
    
int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> test = {{0,0},{1,2},{2,1},{3,6},{2,7},{10,10}};
    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> results;
    auto sorter = [](const Point& p1, const Point& p2) { return std::tie(p1.m_x, p1.m_y) < std::tie(p2.m_x, p2.m_y); };
    
    // sort the items after the beginning and before the end of the sequence
    std::sort(test.begin() + 1, std::prev(test.end()), sorter);
    do
    {
        results.push_back(test);
    } while (std::next_permutation(test.begin() + 1, std::prev(test.end()), sorter));
    
    for (auto& r : results)
    {
        for (auto& p : r)
           std::cout << "{" << p.get_x() << "," << p.get_y() << ") ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{0,0) {1,2) {2,1) {2,7) {3,6) {10,10) 
{0,0) {1,2) {2,1) {3,6) {2,7) {10,10) 
{0,0) {1,2) {2,7) {2,1) {3,6) {10,10) 
{0,0) {1,2) {2,7) {3,6) {2,1) {10,10) 
{0,0) {1,2) {3,6) {2,1) {2,7) {10,10) 
{0,0) {1,2) {3,6) {2,7) {2,1) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,1) {1,2) {2,7) {3,6) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,1) {1,2) {3,6) {2,7) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,1) {2,7) {1,2) {3,6) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,1) {2,7) {3,6) {1,2) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,1) {3,6) {1,2) {2,7) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,1) {3,6) {2,7) {1,2) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,7) {1,2) {2,1) {3,6) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,7) {1,2) {3,6) {2,1) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,7) {2,1) {1,2) {3,6) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,7) {2,1) {3,6) {1,2) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,7) {3,6) {1,2) {2,1) {10,10) 
{0,0) {2,7) {3,6) {2,1) {1,2) {10,10) 
{0,0) {3,6) {1,2) {2,1) {2,7) {10,10) 
{0,0) {3,6) {1,2) {2,7) {2,1) {10,10) 
{0,0) {3,6) {2,1) {1,2) {2,7) {10,10) 
{0,0) {3,6) {2,1) {2,7) {1,2) {10,10) 
{0,0) {3,6) {2,7) {1,2) {2,1) {10,10) 
{0,0) {3,6) {2,7) {2,1) {1,2) {10,10)
```

I chose the sorting criteria based on the x and y values, with the x values being compared first

Comment: I'm a little confused what do you mean by sort. How do I know what criteria to sort it by. Doesn't std::next_permuatation need some sort of criteria? I tried and got a long list of errors.